# Force CMake to rebuild precompiled headers

Tags: c++, cmake, precompiled-headers

How do I get CMake to rebuild all the precompiled headers? (Using g++ and Linux) And how do I get CMake to disable all precompiled headers?

I am getting some build errors that have sprung up and they refer to the `.ch` files. So want to investigate whether this is due to precompiled headers.

Comment: do you have such a big project that you actually need precompiled headers?

Comment: i do. Its a large project . Compilation takes like half an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake, and assuming use of the [`target_precompile_headers()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_precompile_headers.html#command:target_precompile_headers) command, you can disable precompiled headers for a specific CMake target by setting the [`DISABLE_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/DISABLE_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS.html) property:

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES 
    DISABLE_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS ON
)
```

or you can disable precompiled headers for the *entire* project by setting this in the top-level CMake file:

```
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS ON)
```

To get CMake to rebuild all of the precompiled headers, you could simply delete those that have been generated, so they are re-generated.